# References for PCA analysis eigenvalue cut-off (eigenvalues > 1)

Tags: pca, references

I frequently see PCA tutorials that guide us to use principal components with eigenvalues > 1 (e.g., https://www.reneshbedre.com/blog/principal-component-analysis.html). But, I cannot find the reference published in journals.

Can you help me identify where this cut-off started?

Comment: This investigation is unlikely to help you perform any actual PCA analysis, because this rule of thumb frequently does not work.

Comment: This rule, known as Kaiser's criterion, is for _factor analysis_ (FA) only. It is based on PCA's eigenvalues but is used to determine the number of factors to extract, not pr. components. If one uses PCA as a form of FA then yes, the rule applies too. There is  different flavour - using PCA 'as a FA' and using PCA 'as PCA'.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for the detailed comments!!

Comment: @whuber What would be the most valuable approach to do an actual PCA analysis? What are other criteria that are not rule of thumb?

Comment: The textbooks will describe several methods, of which the "scree plot" is the most common.  I believe the better textbooks make it clear that no one method is suitable in all cases.  Sometimes, especially in the physical sciences, one can use auxiliary information to suggest eigenvalue cutoffs.  Other times, when the objective is for EDA or clustering, you just start with the first few PCs and keep adding more until you find a useful pattern or it gets too complicated.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your detailed explanation! I really appreciate your expertise in this.